# Using Java System.in as a press to continue

Tags: java

first sorry if the title isn't clear enough but English isn't my main language so it's a bit hard to explain myself.

I made a simple program that requires you to press Enter so it continues with the code, in my case count to 60 second then wait for another Enter, the problem is that sometimes it bugs and continues as if you had pressed Enter when you didn't (might be because accidentally there is another character pressed before Enter key).

Here is the fragment of code, I used System.in.read() because I read here that it was a good option for what I was looking to do, but I was more experienced with Scanner.

```
public static void cuentaSeries(int n) throws Exception {
   System.out.println("------------------------------");
   int aux = 1;
   while(aux<=n)   {
       System.out.print("Serie Nº" +aux +"  []");
       System.in.read();
       System.out.println("Serie Nº" +aux +"  [X]");
       cuenta();
       aux++;
    }
   System.out.println("------------------------------");
}

public static void cuenta() throws Exception    {
   int contador = 0;
   System.out.print("0 ");
   while(contador<60)   {
       Thread.sleep(1000);
       contador++;
       if(contador%5==0) System.out.print(contador +" ");
       if(contador==60) System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Wrap System.in within a BufferedInputStream, and use `readLine()` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes from the line:

```
System.in.read();
```

See the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read%28%29) that says:

> Reads the next byte of data from the input stream. The value byte is
>   returned as an int in the range 0 to 255.

You are not checking for the enter key but for any single character.  Consider if you got the input '*hello*'.  The System.in.read() will first read 'h', then 'l', etc.  To solve this you need to switch to using nextLine().
Try this:

```
   Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
   int aux = 1;
   while(aux<=n)   {
       System.out.print("Serie Nº" +aux +"  []");
       scan.nextLine();
       System.out.println("Serie Nº" +aux +"  [X]");
       cuenta();
       aux++;
    }
```

with

```
import java.util.Scanner
```